# Not sending XmlHttpRequest with only one parameter called "id"

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm new to javascript. If I try to run this piece of code, the request doesn't gets sent.

```
function getObjectData(objectId)
{
    var url = "FMDiag/getObjectData?id=" + objectId;
    var xmlHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttpRequest.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlHttpRequest.onload = function(e)
    {
        ...
    };
    xmlHttpRequest.send();
}
```

If I change `?id=` to something else, e.g. `?objectId=`, the function works as expected.
Or if I add additional parameters to the request, it works again.

Strange though, `?id=` works from form data sending.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work as expected? How is it expected to work? What resource does the request get sent to? What does the code of that resource look like (i.e. how does it handle your request)? The problem could, in fact, lie on the server, but we can't know that until we have all the information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the problem is not on the server, because I'm currently working on the server-side code. This is an AJAX call. If the name of the parameter is id, the browser doesn't send the request. If its something elese, it does.

Comment: What happens/doesn't happen that makes you think the browser doesn't send the request?

Comment: If the req gets sent, my server immediately answers it, and I can see the traffic in Fiddler too. If I change id to Id, it works. This code is from my test html to test the server code. I wanted to reduce traffic, and changed parameter name objectId to id on both server and client side.

Comment: Can you post the code in your server's resource to which the request is being sent? Looking at just this small piece of AJAX code, there should be no reason why "id" causes the request to fail. That tells me that the problem must lie somewhere else in client or server code.

Comment: No I can't send you server-side code. It's an embedded server in plain C. It is running now in a console and I can see immediately, if it gets a request. If I change ?id= to something else, it works. If I use ?id= from static html form, it works. If I use ?Id= it works.